# Are we sure that there are at most x different types of black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

If I'm not mistaken, there are a limited different types of black holes. Depending on where I look, the black holes are categorized according to size, or categorized according to surroundings and movements (e.g. binary/trinary, rotating), or categorized in to 4 types depending on [rotating/non-rotating and charged/uncharged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric).

So which of the following statements is true?

1. There are exactly 2 different types of black holes.
2. There are exactly 3 different types of black holes .
3. There are exactly 4 different types of black holes.
4. The categorization is somewhat arbitrary or it is not evident that there isn't other types than the aforementioned.

Comment: What do you define as a "type"? Without that, the question isn't really clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The types you mention are not types of black-holes they are the diiferent kinds of solutions of the [Einstein field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) around a black hole. An actual black hole can have mass, charge and angular momentum. There are no different kind of black holes. A black hole can be parameterized by the above quantities. In fact it is thought that they can be parameterized by [only these quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem).
In short - Black holes are not like Pokemon. There is only one kind.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you mean characteristics of black hole solutions. The 'No Hair theorem' states that a black hole can be described by only three classical properties or "hair" i.e. mass, charge and angular momentum. Black holes need to be massive (although there are certain models with higher derivative corrections where the ADM mass vanishes. see http://inspirehep.net/record/1342954) Given this condition, we can have the following possibilities:

a) M $\neq 0, J \neq 0, Q \neq 0$ i.e. Kerr - Newmann type

b) M $\neq 0, J = 0, Q \neq 0$ i.e. Reissner Nördstrom type

c) M $\neq 0, J \neq 0, Q = 0$ i.e. Kerr type

d) M $\neq 0, J  = 0, Q = 0$ i.e. Schwarzschild type

It is also interesting to note that some of the suggestions to the information paradox solution is to break the no hair theorem quantum mechanically i.e allow for quantum hair in which case the black hole would be described by more than just the three properties stated above.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that the no-hair theorem is really the no-hair conjecture: I think it's extremely convincing that it's correct, but a mathematician would probably not think that.

Comment: @tfb Very true!

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing we know is that various solutions to the field equations are unique: the Schwarzschild solution (unrotating, uncharged) is the *only* spherically-symmetric, uncharged, static, vacuum solution for instance, by Birkhoff's theorem.

I am not sure that such a result exists for the Kerr (rotating) solution, or for Kerr-Newmann (rotating, charged).

What I think is generally believed is that all black hole systems will rapidly settle down to something that is, essentially, Kerr-Newmann (and in fact very close to Kerr since large objects (almost?) never have significant charge).  Numerical simulations I think back this up: I don't think there are any proofs, although I'd be happy to be wrong.

So if it's correct that all black hole systems settle down rapidly like this, then there really is only one kind.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is poorly framed.  There are black holes, and we have equations which describe the metric they induce.  The Kerr-Newman metric describes the spacetime around a charged, spinning black hole.  The Kerr-Newman metric reduces to Schwarzschild (neutral, non-rotating) when the charge and spin parameters in Kerr-Newman are 0.

As for classifying them by size, you are totally free to do that, and there are contexts where this is very helpful, but there is nothing intrinsically *different* about a 100 solar mass black hole vs a 100000 solar mass black hole.

And indeed, we can classify them by their surroundings.  Are they near another black hole?  Do they have a disk?  Are they a supermassive black hole at the center of a galaxy?  We can do this, and this might be helpful in certain contexts, but  ultimately, they are all just black holes, which are described by a well-understood set of equations.